# SQLiteAsyncConnection -> CreateTablesAsync<T>() requires two type arguments

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-pcl

OS/X Mac Xamarin Forms Visual Studio Pro 2017

I'm trying to follow the wonderful course by Mosh Hamedani on Xamarin forms. I try to write the same code from lecture 89:

```
var connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
connection.CreateTablesAsync<Recipe>();
```

But... I get the error:

> Using the generic method ... CreateTablesAsync < t1 , t2 > () requires 2
>   type arguments

But even the [Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases) doesn't say that! It only shows one type argument of the table class type that you want the table to be created as.

How do I solve this?

Comment: are you using CreateTableAsync or CreateTablesAsync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateTablesAsync<T1,T2>` requires 2 type arguments.

`CreateTableAsync<T1>` only requires 1 type argument.

You likely have a typo - remove the "s"